# SQL multiple rows as columns (optimizing)

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a SQL query which gives the correct result, but performs too slow.

The query operates on the following three tables:

- `customers` contains lots of customer data like name, address, phone
  etc. To simplify the table i am only using the name.
- `customdatas` contains certain custom (not customer) data. (The
  tables are created in software, which is why the plural form is wrong
  for this table)
- `customercustomdatarels` associates custom data with a customer.

**customers**

```
Id                                  Name            (many more columns)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
8053c6f4c5c5c631054ddb13d9186117    MyCustomer      ...
2efd2aa5711ddfade1f829b12dd88cf3    CheeseFactory   ...
```

**customdata**

```
id                                  key
-------------------------------------------------
22deb172c1af6e8e245634a751871564    favoritsport
86eea84d296df9309ad6ff36fd7f856e    favoritcheese
```

**customercustomdatarels** (relation between customer and custom data - with corresponding value)

```
customer                            customdata                          value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8053c6f4c5c5c631054ddb13d9186117    22deb172c1af6e8e245634a751871564    cycling
8053c6f4c5c5c631054ddb13d9186117    86eea84d296df9309ad6ff36fd7f856e    cheddar
2efd2aa5711ddfade1f829b12dd88cf3    22deb172c1af6e8e245634a751871564    football
2efd2aa5711ddfade1f829b12dd88cf3    86eea84d296df9309ad6ff36fd7f856e    mouldy
```

What i want is a table basically consisting of all data in `customers` with an variable amount of extra columns, corresponding to the custom data specified in `customercustomdatarels`.
These columns should be defined somewhere and I have therefore created the following table which defines such extra columns and maps them to a key in the `customdata` table:

**test_customkeymapping**

```
colkey  customkey
---------------------
1       favoritsport
2       favoritcheese
```

The result should then be:

```
Name            ExtraColumn_1   ExtraColumn_2
---------------------------------------------
CheeseFactory   football        mouldy
MyCustomer      cycling         cheddar
```

(*ExtraColumn_1* is therefore synonym for a customers' favorite sport and *ExtraColumn_2* is a synonym for a customers' favorit cheese.)

This result is achieved by executing the following query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(CASE
                WHEN ckm.colkey = ', colkey, ' THEN
                    (SELECT value FROM customercustomdatarels ccdr2
                     LEFT JOIN customdatas cd2
                       ON cd2.id = ccdr2.customdata
                     WHERE cd2.key = ckm.customkey AND c.Id = ccdr2.customer)
                END) AS ', CONCAT('`ExtraColumn_', colkey, '`'))
    ) INTO @sql
FROM test_customkeymapping;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT c.Name, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM customers c
                   LEFT JOIN customercustomdatarels ccdr
                     ON c.Id = ccdr.customer
                   LEFT JOIN customdatas cd
                     ON cd.Id = ccdr.customdata
                   LEFT JOIN test_customkeymapping ckm 
                     ON cd.key = ckm.customkey
                   GROUP BY c.Id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

This works. But is too slow (for 7000 customers it takes ~10 seconds).
The query was greatly influenced by the solution in this question:
[MySQL Join Multiple Rows as Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462753/mysql-join-multiple-rows-as-columns)

How do I optimize this query?

Comment: Seems like a beginner mistake to want something like this. Usually you should simply accept that the number of columns is static. If you want a dynamic amount of columns the query has to be generated dynamically and this is indeed terrible for performance.

Comment: It's also very hard, if not impossible, to think of a reasonable scenario in which this is useful. It seems you are trying to do something in your database which you should do in your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using a subquery in the `group_concat()` statement.  Wouldn't this generate the code that you really want to run?

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN ckm.colkey = ', colkey, ' THEN ccd.value END) AS ',  
               CONCAT('ExtraColumn_', colkey, ''))
    ) INTO @sql
FROM test_customkeymapping;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT c.Name, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM customers c
                   LEFT JOIN customercustomdatarels ccdr
                     ON c.Id = ccdr.customer
                   LEFT JOIN customdatas cd
                     ON cd.Id = ccdr.customdata
                   LEFT JOIN test_customkeymapping ckm 
                     ON cd.key = ckm.customkey
                   GROUP BY c.Id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Note:  This is untested, but the idea is the same.  Use the values from the main `from` statement for your work rather than the values from some extra, unnecessary subquery.

Comment: Thanks. That certainly simplifies the query. I don't know why i couldn't see the sub query was unnecessary at that moment. The execution time is almost identical however.

Comment: @CleanUp . . . Do you have indexes on the `join` keys?  It is also possible that your data is sufficiently large that the `group by` takes time.  In your case, that would be due to wide columns rather than numbers of rows.

Comment: There is a lot of data, but the key issue was some missing indexes for some of the keys as you pointed out. I think it will perform sufficiently - for now at least. Thank you very much.