# MySQL join varchar rows from another table into columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join two tables so that the data stored in rows of table 2 are joined as columns onto table 1.

work_tickets:

```
wt_id  problem
1        TV
2        Lights
3        TV
```

wt_follow_up

```
follow_up_id   wt_id   description
1                1      not at home
2                2      changed bulb
3                1      fixed tv
```

Currently:

```
wt_id    problem   description
1        TV        not at home
1        TV        fixed tv
2        Lights    changed bulb
3
```

desired:

```
wt_id    problem   follow_up1      follow_up2
1         TV       not at home     fixed tv
2         Lights   changed bulb
3         TV
```

I've look at [SQL multiple rows as columns (optimizing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531320/sql-multiple-rows-as-columns-optimizing) and [MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns), but these are not based on text data.

Comment: This one isn't based on varchar data either. How many follow ups are possible?

Comment: any number of follow ups are possible