# Making columns from values - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Below the table as I have it. I have an alias column with a value. 
I'm trying to make dynamic columns from the alias. The aliases are dynamic so they can change.

[MySQL Join Multiple Rows as Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462753/mysql-join-multiple-rows-as-columns) here they have 2 tables that they join, I have only one. But still I can't get it to work. I wonder if I really need a prepare statement.

When I use

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('value AS ', alias))
```

I'm get that piece of query as column name.

---

```
ID   value    alias
1    aaa      test1
1    bbb      test2
1    ccc      test3
2    ddd      test1
2    eee      test2
2    fff      test3
```

The desired result right from the MySQL query is:

```
ID    test1    test2    test3
1     aaa      bbb      ccc
2     ddd      eee      fff
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times.

Answer (score 0):

A simple pivot query should work here:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN alias = 'test1' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS test1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN alias = 'test2' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS test2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN alias = 'test3' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS test3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is cool, but the aliases are dynamic. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Tim van Uum:  The statement in this answer will produce the resultset. If you want this to be dynamic, to have a varying number of columns, or different column aliases, that can't be done dynamically within a single SQL statement. The dynamic part of the process, a separate step,  produces this SQL text to be executed.