# Select rows with same id but different result in another column

Tags: sql

sql: I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+
|ID    |Result|
+------+------+
|1     |A     |
+------+------+
|2     |A     |
+------+------+
|3     |A     |
+------+------+
|1     |B     |
+------+------+
|2     |B     |
+------+------+
```

The output should be something like:

Output:

```
+------+-------+-------+
|ID    |Result1|Result2|
+------+-------+-------+
|1     |A      |B      |
+------+-------+-------+
|2     |A      |B      |
+------+-------+-------+
|3     |A      |       |
+------+-------+-------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please reformat the content. It's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Id,
    MAX((CASE result WHEN 'A' THEN 'A' ELSE NULL END)) result1,
    MAX((CASE result WHEN 'B' THEN 'B' ELSE NULL END)) result2,
FROM 
    table1
GROUP BY Id
```

results

```
+------+-------+-------+
|Id    |Result1|Result2|
+------+-------+-------+
|1     |A      |B      |
|2     |A      |B      |
|3     |A      |NULL   |
+------+-------+-------+
```

run live demo on SQL fiddle: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1081/2)

Comment: This would only work if the only two possible values are A and B - something which is _implied_ by the OP, though not confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways to do it.
None of tehm a are straight forward.
in theory, a simple way would be to create 2 temporary tables, where you separte the data, all the "A" resultas in one table and "B" in another table.

Then get the results with simple query. using JOIN.

if you are allowed to use some scrpting  on the process then it is simpler, other wise you need a more complex logic on your query. And for you query to alwasy work, you need to have some rules like, A table always contains more ids than B table.

If you post your real example, it is easier to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

for this reason:

ID       Name        filename

1001     swapan      4566.jpg
1002     swapan      678.jpg
1003     karim       7688.jpg
1004     tarek       7889.jpg
1005     karim       fdhak.jpg

output:

ID       Name        filename

1001     swapan      4566.jpg    678.jpg
1003     karim       7688.jpg    fdhak.jpg
1004     tarek       7889.jpg    ...
..       ...         ...         ...

Comment: SO does not work like this. You have to update the question to provide that new sample data and inform us that the `filename` column might have *unpredictable* values

Comment: check this question ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462753/mysql-join-multiple-rows-as-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462753/mysql-join-multiple-rows-as-columns))